# Weird IE7 float image bug

Tags: internet-explorer-7

IE7 (or newer IE in compatibility mode) is doing this weird thing where a floated image is clearing the text that's in the same list item element.  I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2uKQr/) for viewing. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you set the background of the list item to your image and set the padding accordingly?

```
background: url("http://hosting.bwilliams.dev.genares.net/sites/hosting.bwilliams.dev.genares.net/files/styles/amenity_icon/public/amenity-icons/health_club_0.gif") no-repeat;
```

Comment: I've updated your link, don't know if you can see it: http://jsfiddle.net/2uKQr/1/

Comment: Normally, that would be fine, but this content is being generated by a CMS and I don't have the ability to create the custom css for each image that the client may upload.

Comment: Will the text always come before the image in the <li> element?

Comment: I could probably do something with a lot of effort to reprogram how the CMS spits out the HTML.  I may do that if no one has a solution to the IE7 bug.  But it would be really cool if someone did know of a solution.

Comment: Will your CMS allow you to point to an alternate stylesheet specifically for IE7?  That's the only way I can see you achieving what you want.

Comment: I went ahead and changed the way the HTML generates.  But I'm still curious to see if anyone has a fix for the actual IE7 Bug.

Comment: I've got a funny feeling it can't :(  Might be worth setting a bounty on this??